# Appium execute duplicate test classes in testsuite

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium

My team is trying to develop test automation with Appium. 
We would like to do one time execute all test classes in a test suite. 
Now we are facing a problem when one test class need to execute many times in the test suite, the test class doesn't execute in sequently.

Example :

- I have testA.class, testB.class, testC.class.
- in my test suite 
  `@Suite.SuiteClasses({testA.class, testB.class, testC.class, testB.class})`

=> my expected result is : `testA.class > testB.class > testC.class > testB.class`

But actual result : `testA.class > testB.class` (it is the last B class). Appium skips the 2 middle classes.

Please give me some advice.

Thank you in advance for all the support.

Comment: Try the [session-override flag](http://discuss.appium.io/t/run-multiple-tests-on-single-device-one-after-the-other/351)

Comment: @lloyd I'll try. Thank you :)